# Which are the credentials used to copy an object to a Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I need to copy an object (file) to a Cloud Storage bucket named `destination-bucket1`.

Only service account named `service-account1` was provided write access to `destination-bucket1` by administrator, and no personal account has any access to the `destination-bucket1`. 
Besides, it is not allowed to create a key for that service account (`service-account1`) by existing policy.

I'm accessing a Compute Engine VM instance via SSH named `instance1` which is under the same `service-account1`, so `instance1` has access to `destination-bucket1` via `service-account1`.

If I run the command `gsutil cp file1.bin gs://destination-bucket1` using the Cloud SDK credentials, I use my own credentials to access `destination-bucket1`. That is why this operations should fail - because of access denied.

The question is, if I execute the below command via SSH in `instance1`

```
gsutil cp file1.bin gs://destination-bucket1
```

Shall I use credentials of `instance1` service account `service-account1` or my own credentials?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the credentials of an account with permissions to write into the bucket.

If your own account have permissions to write into the bucket and you want to use it you can login into your account from the VM using the command `gcloud auth login`

In order to use gsutil cp command in a Compute Engine using it's own default service account you need to:

Access your instance through the console, stop it, press edit, scroll down to access scopes and set the storage scope to read and write or full access.

Then go to your bucket and edit your permissions, you can make the service account of your Compute Engine the bucket owner, reader... as needed.

Go to APIs & services and enable Storage Transfer API

Then remove the old gsutil permissions from your VM by running this command oin your instance:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.gsutil
```

Now you should be good to go with your gsutil command

Comment: Thank you @Chris32, I should add, that destination bucket is not my own bucket, moreover, it is located in different project. I am even not the project owner of my project.

Comment: Do both the projects belong to the same organisation?

Comment: @Alister you will def need permissions. If you want to transfer the entire bucket to another project you can attempt using [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service/) and if you want to copy a objects, you can simply use the gsutil cmd you're using with a service account with the correct permissions.

Comment: DuDoff, I tried to experiment with copying file into bucket inside my project via gsutil in GCE SSH and it seems like file is copied under service-account1 credentials even without any additional attempts. So I suppose copying file to foreign bucket will succeed.